# python: read file and split the data

Tags: python

I have a file config and the contents are separated by space " "

cat config

```
/home/user1 *.log,*.txt 30
/home/user2 *.trm,*.doc,*.jpeg 10
```

I want to read this file,parse each line and print each field from the each line.

Ex:-

```
Dir = /home/user1 
Fileext = *.log,*.txt
days=30
```

I couldn't go further than the below..

```
def dir():
        file = open('config','r+')
        cont = file.readlines()
        print "file contents are %s" % cont
        for i in range(len(cont)):
                j = cont[i].split(' ')

dir()
```

Any pointers how to move further?

Comment: What is it, that's not working?

Comment: If those are actually configuration files, consider using [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) instead of writing your own parsing code. And lhcgeneva's comment is getting at something important: tell us specifically what the problem is. Is that code raising exceptions? Are you getting bad results? Is it just not complete and you don't know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, you are just missing the last step processing each element of the splitted string, try this:

```
def dir():
    file = open('config','r+')
    cont = file.readlines()
    print "file contents are %s" % cont + '\n'
    elements = []
    for i in range(len(cont)):
        rowElems = cont[i].split(' ')
        elements.append({ 'dir' : rowElems[0], 'ext' : rowElems[1], 'days' : rowElems[2] })

for e in elements:
    print "Dir = " + e['dir']
    print "Fileext = " + e['ext']
    print "days = " + e['days']

dir()
```

At the end of this code, you will have all the rows processed and stored in an array of dictionaries you can easily access later.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function to parse each line, and then use the `map` function to apply that function against each line in `file.readlines()`:

```
def parseLine(line):
    # function to split and parse each line,
    #  and return the formatted string
    Dir, FileExt, Days = line.split(' ')[:3]
    return 'Dir = {}\nFileext = {}\nDays = {}'.format(Dir, FileExt, Days)

def dir():
    with open('config','r+') as file:
        print 'file contents are\n' + '\n'.join(map(parseLine, file.readlines()))
```

Results:

```
>>> dir()

file contents are

Dir = /home/user1
Fileext = *.log,*.txt
Days = 30

Dir = /home/user2
Fileext = *.trm,*.doc,*.jpeg
Days = 10
```

Comment: You're welcome @sameer, but please consider upvoting the answer if it is helpful, as that is the common way of saying "thanks" here.